# Basic doubt in echo statement

Tags: command-line, echo

I have just started learning unix and came across very basic doubt in command line arguments.

Suppose if in my script i do:

```
echo $@ #Now this prints all the command line arguments

args=$@ #Args array will take the command line argument array from $@

echo $args
```

Here i have doubt in last statement. `echo arrayname` as it should print only first index element but why is it showing the complete array?

If i take a normal array in unix and say array name is ARR,now if i use echo ARR,it will show me first element and not all elements.So why the behaviour is different with args above?

Comment: If `args` is an actual array (Jesse_b's answer), then `$args` is equivalent to `${args[0]}` -- I can't tell you why, some historical quirk probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's printing every element because you have set a variable and not an array.  To set an array you would need to do:

```
args=($@)
```

Comment: ok.But i i try to access this variable as an array and use echo ${args[0]},then it is able to read the first index.How is this possible?

Comment: @rahulsharma: I cannot reproduce what you describe.

Comment: See here https://pastebin.com/HGbUVm7C  .The second and third line gives me same output if i call my script with 3 arguments.Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: @rahulsharma: I'm not sure what you are showing me but `args = $@` is a syntax error.  No output is shown either.

Answer (score 1):

`$@` behaves differently from an ordinary array variable without index because `$@` has an "integrated index": It always means "all elements".

```
set -- a b c
echo $@
    a b c
set -x
var=$@
    + var='a b c'
ar=(a b c)
    + ar=(a b c)
echo $ar
    + echo a
    a
```